# How can I really force the hyphenation points of a word?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I try to make XeLaTeX hyphenate the German word "Sicherheitsbeauftragter". I tried several values for `x` in `\tolerance=x` and instances of `\hyphenation{Si-cher-heits-be-auf-trag-ter}`. Nothing worked. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\hyphenation{Si-cher-heits-be-auf-trag-ter} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{7.7em}@{|}}
Sicherheitsbeauftragter\\
Technischer Leiter
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of hyphenation not working]

I also tried `babel` instead of polyglossia and `pdfLaTeX` instead of `XeLaTeX`  but except for how the "|" looks, there is no difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\hspace{0pt}` right before `Sicherheitsbeauftragter` allows TeX to break the word, because TeX does not hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. (AFAIK this had made the implementation easier and in English with the many short words, it wasn't much of a problem.)

Since the `\hspace` inserts a break point at this place, this can be avoided by `\nobreak` in horizontal mode:

```
\leavevmode\nobreak\hspace{0pt}Sicherheitsbeauftragter
```

Or the star form of `\hspace` can be used:

```
\hspace*{0pt}Sicherheitsbeauftragter
```

This can be automated (see Herbert's comment) in the column description:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace*{0pt}}p{7.7em}@{|}}
```

Comment: Also `\selectlanguage{german}` should be issued before `\hyphenation` or, maybe preferably, the command should be between `\begin{otherlanguage*}` and `\end{otherlanguage*}`.

Comment: @egreg The OP has used `\setmainlanguage{german}` (package `polyglossia`).

Comment: or use `\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{7.7em}@{|}}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Try adding `\showthe\language` just before `\hyphenation`, you'll get 0.

Comment: @egreg It's 30 for me after `\begin{document}`. `\hyphenation` is no longer necessary, the hyphenation with the `ngerman` patterns (`loadhyph-de-1996` or `dehyphn-x-2012-05-30`) is correct.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, after `\begin{document}` it's set to the correct number. But in the OP's question it's before. I agree that the `\hyphenation` command isn't needed in this particular case.

Answer (score 15):

You can also suggest places for hyphenation using `\-`. The following works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\RaggedRight}p{7.7em}@{|}}
Sicherheits\-be\-auf\-tragter\\
Technischer Leiter
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem here is, that the word is read from a source file, in which "\-" shouldn't occur (aka readable to non-texies).

Comment: Ah, then in that case Heiko's answer is a much more suitable solution.

Comment: This (``\-``) worked for me with no package. I used it for one specific word that was refusing to break. Useful trick.